# Change language at runtime in android

Tags: android

Is It possible that I can change the whole application strings, text at run time without using separate value folders?

```
myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    saveLocale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = myLocale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

values folder is required for this code.

Comment: @XaverKapeller I am developing an app in which English and German languages are the two options and around 60-70 are the strings used. A solution which I found is to translate every string and make a new values folder for them. Just want the another alternative if possible.

Comment: there is no other alternative. That's how it's supposed to work. If you supply your translations like this Android picks the correct translations based on the language of the user prefers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1.try like this it work for me


 public static void changeLanguage(String languageCode, Context context) 
  {
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        context.getApplicationContext().getResources()
                .updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics());

    }
```

Comment: use this method when your application contains an language chooser.

Comment: This doesn't change the language until you reload the activity/fragment, e.g. by switching to another one, then loading the first one again.